# Removing redundant data from mysql

Tags: mysql, redundancy

I have a table in sql which looks like:

```
        1   1w10    U   UROK_HUMAN  IIGGEFTTIENQPWFAAIYRRHRGGSVTYVCGGSLISPCWVISATHCFID...   
        2   1w11    U   UROK_HUMAN  IIGGEFTTIENQPWFAAIYRRHRGGSVTYVCGGSLISPCWVISATHCFID...   
        3   1w12    U   UROK_HUMAN  IIGGEFTTIENQPWFAAIYRRHRGGSVTYVCGGSLISPCWVISATHCFID...   
        4   1w13    U   UROK_HUMAN  IIGGEFTTIENQPWFAAIYRRHRGGSVTYVCGGSLISPCWVISATHCFID...   
        5   1w14    U   UROK_HUMAN  IIGGEFTTIENQPWFAAIYRRHRGGSVTYVCGGSLISPCWVISATHCFID...
        6   1w15    A   SYT4_RAT    GSPGISGGGGGIPSGRGELLVSLCYQSTTNTLTVVVLKARHLPKSDVSGL...   
        7   1w16    A   SYT4_RAT    GSPGISGGGGGIPSGRGELLVSLCYQSTTNTLTVVVLKARHLPKSDVSGL...   
        8   1w17    B   PDAA_BACSU  MKWMCSICCAAVLLAGGAAQAEAVPNEPINWGFKRSVNHQPPDAGKQLNS...   
        10  1w18    B   SACB_ACEDI  AGVPGFPLPSIHTQQAYDPQSDFTARWTRADALQIKAHSDATVAAGQNSL...   
        12  1w18    E   SACB_ACEDI  MKGGAGVPDLPSLDASGVRLAIVASSWHGKICDALLDGARKVAAGCGLDD...
```

I want to remove duplicate entries but leaving one of them. For instance, I want to keep the first row but remove 2,3,4,5. In short, I want to remove rows which have same column 4 value (here, UROK-HUMAN) but have different col2 and col3 values( here 1w10, 1w11 etc (col2) and U,A,B(col3)).

However, I do not want to remove entry have same col2 and col3 (1w18 B-E) which have same col4 value(SACB-ACEDI).

How can I write and sql statement to delete those rows? I tried to write like and did not work:

```
SELECT pdb, chain, unp, sekans, COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM protein
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(unp)
          FROM protein 
          GROUP by pdb) protein2 ON protein2.unp = protein.unp;
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your "delete" statement doesn't contain the DELETE keyword...

Comment: that's because I have a problem in the selection part. putting delete there is just a piece of cake :) as I just wrote, without writing a php or java code, I just wanna delete all duplicate rows except one of them. But thanks for your comment

Comment: "putting delete there is just a piece of cake" Really? Have you ever tried in MySQL to delete from a table from which you are selecting?

Comment: sure I did:) As I told, I wanna delete some rows but first I should select them without iterating over each row and comparing its attributes with previous row in the php or java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not writing it for you but I'll tell how to do that. First write a SELECT query that would return all the IDs (I guess it is the first column, right?) you want to delete.

Then write a DELETE statement that would delete all of the rows with those IDs. Something like:

```
DELETE from protein where pdb in
(SELECT pdb from protein #here_goes_the_query_im_not_writing#)
```

So, in short, you first get all the IDs you want to delete and then you tell the DBMs to delete those IDs. That's all.

**EDIT:** Just adding a possible SQL to get all the duplicated rows but one. Not tested.

```
SELECT pdb FROM protein WHERE
pdb not in (
    SELECT pdb FROM (
        SELECT sekans, pdb FROM protein
        GROUP BY sekans)
    as T);
```

Comment: The problem is selecting the parts that I want to delete. I have a huge dataset and I do not know which rows have duplicate unp entries with different pdbs. That's why I did not put the delete part. I guess I have to write a Java method to get the duplicate entries' IDs and delete all except one. I just wanna find a way to do that with sql to decrease the computation time.

Comment: Please, take a look at the awful SQL code I've provided at the end. Maybe it can guide you to a solution.

Comment: OMG !!! I completely forgot to use Group By to get one row representing a group :s I modified your sql and used. Thank you very very much reminding that useful function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the alternative route instead: selecting those unique rows and inserting them into a temp table, then drop the old one and rename the new one. This circumvents the limitations on deleting from a table you select on, and it makes it far easier to test wether the results are correct.

```
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT min(pdb), chain, unp, sekans
FROM protein
GROUP by chain, unp, sekans
```

Note that if you have other columns that could have a different value in different rows (like the pdb), you should use an aggregate function (like min, max, sum, group_concat), or else the value that mysql will use for the new row will be undefined.